# Want to use the HTML tags in the body(Text Editor) of SENDEmail Action

Tags: sitecore-forms

[image]
want to implement the Html tags in the body to send the data in mail in the tabular form.

I tried to figure out its Template so that we can design a custom Template and inherit it but it’s inside the core database and coming through a ViewRendering “RichTextEditor”.

Any Suggestion what we can do over here.